# Visual Studio Remote Testing - Add additional docker run arguments

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio, unit-testing, remote-debugging

I'm using the remote testing feature from Visual Studio to execute my unit tests on a Linux container.

For this, I have the following `Dockerfile.test`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
RUN mkdir /usr/local/temp

RUN wget https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh && \
    sh getvsdbgsh -v latest  -l /vsdbg
```

And the following `testenvironments.json`

```json
{
    "version": "1",
    "environments": [
        {
            "name": "GitServiceUnix",
            "type": "docker",
            "dockerFile": "Dockerfile.test"
        }
    ]
}
```

Working fine as it should.

Now I came to the point that I have to mount a volume into the testing container.

1. Is there any way to add additional docker run arguments like in the Debug Properties?
2. Is the remote testing also working with a docker-compose file?
3. Can I build & run the container myself and tell Visual Studio to execute the remote test on this container?

Answer (score 0):

1. Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/remote-testing?view=vs-2022#local-container-connections there is not a documented way to add a volume
2. You can start a container and then connect using SSH: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/remote-testing?view=vs-2022#ssh-connections.